# embedding <script> tags in body.. what are the implications?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, web

I love to embed `<script>` tags in the `<body>` and its all over the place. This have the implication that the generated code becomes human-unreadable.. but my concern is.. other than that what other implications do we have?

Is it true that a browser has to do more "work" when we have like 300 generated stand-alone  tags embedded all over the place within the  tag?

Comment: nt related to this question: what framework do you work with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Each time the browser encounters a `<script>` tag, it needs to fire up a Javascript interpreter.

However, you shouldn't worry about that; you should use whatever approach is easiest to understand and debug.

Comment: Normally I'd say that the "startup" cost for the browser innards to invoke JavaScript are pretty minimal, but if there are really 300 of them then it could become a significant factor :-)

Comment: btw so does it mean that actually there is a better solution to the way that ASP.Net injects code? (they love to do tons of `<script>`  tags within `<body>`)

Comment: Don't worry about it.  (And the location of the `<script>` tag does not affect performance at all)

Answer (score 1):

You get a bigger chunk of text to send to the client every time someone requests your page. This is because normally pages aren't cached which means that if you request the same page several times, everything needs to be re-downloadeded from the server.

However if you on the other hand places all your JavaScript code in a seperate .js file you can easily cache, minify and gzip that file, which can make a huge difference in the end. The same is true for inline css vs css in an external file also.

Comment: usually the stuff within the `<script>` which i embed within the `<body>` are dynamic stuff that are not cache-able anyway (the cacheable js i do put them in the head of course..)

Comment: But I do think you are doing it wrong if you are using script tags in the body just because you are building dynamic stuffs. Would love to hear some examples where you absolutely need to do it inline on the page, instead of in an external javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

If your page has static code within the <script> tags, consider placing such code within functions in a separate .js file with just calls to the functions in web pages.

Also, <script>s should also make use of the [defer="defer](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp)" option if the script is not needed to render the page (e.g., the code within is only active after the page loads... such as code used in "on" stuff. This allows browsers to put off compiling the scripts within until after page load so you may get a slightly snappier response.

Comment: btw the embedded code are all the dynamic stuff.. the static stuff i do put them in the head referring to a .js file like the usual way